# Cons of setInterval to auto-refresh data on mobile devices due to data usage?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am working on a web app using jQuery Mobile, that calls a URL via AJAX to request JSON objects, which I then parse and display to the user on their mobile device in the form of a list. The information changes constantly, so I want to refresh the data on the users mobile device every 10 seconds.

Are there any best practices or warnings about doing this due to the data consumption? If a user has a mobile phone with a set data plan, i'm concerned about eating away at their available data, even though my JSON calls are quite small (approx 1.2k). Should you warn the user? Is there an "acceptable" data size? When the user minimizes their browser to the background, will the requests keep generating?

I can't seem to find any information about this concern. I apologize if this has been asked before. I spent a good deal of time digging for the answer before posting. If anyone could point me to a link that addresses this topic I would be very grateful.

Thank you!